# Would this relation be an equivalence relation?

Tags: logic, relations, equivalence-relations

I am a bit stuck on this one question from my homework and for some reason it isn't making any sense to me. I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain it to me how I can go about to solving it.

Suppose that $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$ are equivalence relations on the set $S$. Define a new relation $\sim_v$ so that
$$a \sim_v b \Leftrightarrow a\sim_1 b \vee a\sim_2 b.$$

Is $\sim_v$ always an equivalence relation? (Specifically, it is true that for every pair of equivalence relations $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$ the relation $\sim_v$ is an equivalence relation?) If so, prove it. If not, give an example where it fails and explain why it fails for your example.

Comment: My approach here would be attempt to prove that $\sim_v$ is an equivalence relation, and see if this goes badly wrong at any point. Either your proof succeeds, or you should see where the problem is, helping you to construct a counterexample.

Comment: You can have $a\sim_1b$ and $b\sim_2 c$ but neither $a\sim_1c$ nor $a\sim_2c$ so you might not have the transitive property.

Comment: To show that it's an equivalence relation, you need to show 3 properties, do you know what they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason Bourne has given a concrete example, but I think that it might be helpful to see the approach that Matt Pressland suggested in the comments. Suppose that $S,\sim_1,\sim_2$, and $\sim_v$ are as given; we’ll try to prove that $\sim_v$ is an equivalence relation on $S$ and see what happens.

- **Reflexivity:** If $x\in S$, then $x\sim_1 x$, so $x\sim_v x$. Thus, $\sim_v$ is reflexive.
- **Symmetry:** If $x,y\in S$ and $x\sim_v y$, then $x\sim_1 y$ or $x\sim_2 y$. Without loss of generality $x\sim_1 y$; but then $y\sim_1 x$, so $y\sim_v x$, and $\sim_v$ is symmetric.
- **Transitivity:** Suppose that $x,y,z\in S$ and $x\sim_v y\sim_v z$. Then $x\sim_i y$ for at least one $i\in\{1,2\}$, and $y\sim_j z$ for at least one $j\in\{1,2\}$. If we can choose $i$ and $j$ to be equal, we’re in business: if $x\sim_1 y\sim_1 z$, for instance, then $x\sim_1 z$ by transitivity of $\sim_1$, and therefore $x\sim_v z$. But what if we can’t choose $i$ and $j$ to be equal? What if $x\sim_1 y\sim_2 z$, $x\not\sim_2 y$, and $y\not\sim_1 z$? Then there’s no obvious guarantee that either $x\sim_1 z$ or $x\sim_2 z$. It’s conceivable, of course, that there’s some guarantee that **isn’t** obvious, but there’s so little here to work with that it doesn’t really seem likely. At this point a better bet is to try to find a specific counterexample: a set $S$ and equivalence relations $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$ on $S$ such that $\sim_v$ is not transitive.

This can be done in a very visual way if you understand the connection between equivalence relations on $S$ and partitions of $S$. Consider a four-element set:

$$\begin{array}{|cc|} \hline
a&b\\
c&d\\ \hline
\end{array}\tag{1}$$

I can partition it into rows to get

$$\begin{array}{|cc|} \hline
a&b\\ \hline
c&d\\ \hline
\end{array}\;;$$

the associated equivalence relation $\sim_1$ has $x\sim_1 y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same row of $(1)$.

I can also partition it into columns to get

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
a&b\\
c&d\\ \hline
\end{array}\;;$$

the associated equivalence relation $\sim_2$ has $x\sim_2 y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same column of $(1)$.

Now $x\sim_v y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same row or the same column of $(1)$. Thus, $a\sim_v a$, $a\sim_v b$, and $a\sim_v c$, but $a\not\sim_v d$. In fact, $x\sim_v y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are not the two ends of a diagonal in $(1)$. Thus, $a\sim_v b\sim_v d$, but as we already saw, $a\not\sim_v d$.

---

Recall that $\sim_1,\sim_2$, and $\sim_v$ are actually subsets of $S\times S$. In fact, $\sim_v=\sim_1\cup\sim_2$. This is a bit hard to read, so let me replace the names $\sim_1,\sim_2$, and $\sim_v$ by $E_1,E_2$, and $E_v$, respectively, and write $E_v=E_1\cup E_2$. This exercise shows that the union of two equivalence relations is not necessarily an equivalence relation. (The **intersection** of two equivalence relations, on the other hand, always **is** an equivalence relation; if you’ve not done so, you might find it a useful exercise to prove this.) For any equivalence relations $E_1$ and $E_2$ on a set $S$ there **is** a smallest equivalence relation $E$ on $S$ such that $E_1\cup E_2\subseteq E$, but it usually isn’t simply $E_1\cup E_2$. It turns out that $xEy$ if and only if for some $n$ there are $x_0,\dots,x_n\in S$ such that $x_0=x$, $x_n=y$, and $x_{k-1}(E_1\cup E_2)x_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$. In other words, $xEy$ if and only if you can get from $x$ to $y$ be a finite chain of steps, each of which takes you from an element $x_{k-1}$ of $S$ to an element $x_k$ that is related to $x_{k-1}$ by at least one of the two equivalence relations $E_1$ and $E_2$.

In the little example above, for instance, there is such a path from $a$ to any of the four elements of the set, so $a$ is related to $a,b,c$, and $d$. In fact, in this simple example $E$ turns out to be the trivial equivalence relation $S\times S$: everything in $S$ is $E$-related to everything in $S$. Equality is the equivalence relation on $S$ that makes the most distinctions: each element of $S$ gets its own equivalence class. The trivial equivalence relation $S\times S$ is the one that makes the fewest: it lumps all of $S$ into a single equivalence class.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it!!! :)

Comment: @Mohamed: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I'm also wondering, would this be also similar for the relation if suppose instead of it being ~v, it was ~/\. (Sorry for the strange symbols, not really sure how to do the fancy version, but that upside down V is the "and" symbol. Or would it hold, because for it to be a relation, it would have to hold for when it is a ~1 b ~2 c and a ~2 b ~1 c?

Comment: @Mohamed: You mean defining $x\sim_{\land}y$ if and only if $x\sim_1 y$ **and** $x\sim_2 y$? Yes, that’s an equivalence relation. In fact, it’s the one that I suggested you might want to try to prove: it’s the intersection of $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$.

Answer (score 7):

Define $\sim_1$ on the set of integers such that $a\sim_1 b$ if and only if $b-a$ is divisible by $2$.

Define $\sim_2$ on the set of integers such that $a\sim_2 b$ if and only if $b-a$ is divisible by $3$.

Define $\sim_v$ on the set of integers such that $a\sim_v b$ if and only if $a\sim_1 b$ or $a\sim_2 b$.

Verify that the first two are equivalence relations but the last is not as it is not transitive.